# Pass a simple variable using jQ & Ajax to Ruby

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, variables

I'm new to Ruby overall (and to jQ and Ajax as well) but I always try to read before posting.

I have not been able to send a simple variable of jQuery to a Ruby controller using Ajax (for a smooth transition).

It's possible with AJAX pass simple variable to ruby controller?

It's necessary, any other help of script language like PHP or ASP.NET??

Is there another easier way to do that?

**controller.rb**

```
def show_NuevaVista
  app_info(@params['myparam'])
    @show_text = @params['myparam']
  render :action => :test, :back => '/app'  #test is a view that shows the global var show_text
end
```

**view.rb**

```
<button id="botonTweet" >More Tweets</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#botonTweet').click(function(slice) {
    var stub = 1;                               //variable to be sent
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "show_NuevaVista",         //method of the controller
        data: {
          "test": stub                //try to send this variable 
        },
      });
  });
});
</script>
```

**Update:**

The only way its possible for me to send a variable is with href and that the variable is declared in ruby.

```
<%= @texto = "LOL!" %>
<%= link_to "Click Here!", :action => :show_NuevaVista,:query => {:myparam => @texto} %>
```

Comment: The unusual way I did this was using the following code:

<%= @show_text %>
<%= link_to "Click Here!", :action => :show_NuevaVista,:query => {:myparam => @texto} %>

Comment: What is this line for? data isn't defined.

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

Comment: Sorry I erased some extra code I had, but its been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the link_to & jQuery coded, after the ajax call it will still exocute the href.  You can either do the following:

```
<%= link_to("Click Here", "javascript:void(0);", :id => "botonTweet") %>
```

Or if you want the href execution as fallback, use your same link_to code and update your javascript to return false after the ajax call :

```
$('#botonTweet').click(function(slice) {
var stub = 1;                               //variable to be sent
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "show_NuevaVista",         //method of the controller
    data: {
      "test": stub                //try to send this variable 
    },
  });
  //this is the key to avoid href redirect
  return false;
});
```